Python Kivy - Center a opened file in paint app
I'm a pretty much beginner coder creating a python paint app using kivy but when I open a file to draw on it, it only opens in the bottom left whereas I would like it to open it at the center and bigger, my app ain't that pretty at the moment but i'd rather make everything work before making it pretty, can you help me ?
from kivy.config import Config
# Les configurations doivent être définies avant d'importer d'autres modules Kivy
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle, Fbo, ClearColor, ClearBuffers
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window


class WidgetPaint(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WidgetPaint, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.largeur_ligne = 15
        self.largeur_point = 30
        self.dessin = False
        self.couleur = (1, 1, 1, 1)

    def definir_largeur_ligne(self, largeur):
        self.largeur_ligne = largeur

    def definir_largeur_point(self, largeur):
        self.largeur_point = largeur

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.dessin = True
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*self.couleur)
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - self.largeur_point / 2, touch.y - self.largeur_point / 2), size=(self.largeur_point, self.largeur_point))
            touch.ud['ligne'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=self.largeur_ligne)

    def definir_couleur(self, couleur):
        self.couleur = couleur

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        ligne = touch.ud.get('ligne')
        if ligne:
            ligne.points += [touch.x, touch.y]

    def effacer_toile(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.dessin = False


class AppPaint(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.peintre = WidgetPaint()

        slider = Slider(min=1, max=70, value=15, size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 50), pos=(295, 60))
        slider.bind(value=self.adjust_brush_size)

        btn_ouvrir = Button(text='Ouvrir', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos=(150, 285))
        btn_ouvrir.bind(on_release=lambda instance: self.ouvrir_fichier())

        btn_effacer = Button(text='Effacer', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos=(40, 585))
        btn_effacer.bind(on_release=self.effacer_toile)

        btn_ligne_fine = Button(text='T1', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(105, 60))
        btn_ligne_fine.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.configurer_peintre(5, 10))

        btn_ligne_epaisse = Button(text='T2', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(155, 60))
        btn_ligne_epaisse.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.configurer_peintre(15, 30))

        btn_ligne_plus_epaisse = Button(text='T3', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(205, 60))
        btn_ligne_plus_epaisse.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.configurer_peintre(25, 50))

        btn_ligne_encore_plus_epaisse = Button(text='T4', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(255, 60))
        btn_ligne_encore_plus_epaisse.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.configurer_peintre(35, 70))

        btn_quitter = Button(text='Enregistrer & Quitter', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos=(40, 285))
        btn_quitter.bind(on_release=lambda instance: self.enregistrer())

        btn_rouge = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(5, 5), background_color=(5, 0, 0, 1))
        btn_rouge.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((5, 0, 0, 1)))

        btn_vert = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(55, 5), background_color=(0, 5, 0, 1))
        btn_vert.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((0, 5, 0, 1)))

        btn_bleu = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(105, 5), background_color=(0, 0, 5, 1))
        btn_bleu.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((0, 0, 5, 1)))

        btn_jaune = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(155, 5), background_color=(5, 5, 0, 1))
        btn_jaune.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((5, 5, 0, 1)))

        btn_turquoise = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(205, 5), background_color=(0, 5, 5, 1))
        btn_turquoise.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((0, 5, 5, 1)))

        btn_rose = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(255, 5), background_color=(5, 0, 5, 1))
        btn_rose.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((5, 0, 5, 1)))

        btn_blanc = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(305, 5), background_color=(5, 5, 5, 1))
        btn_blanc.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur((5, 5, 5, 1)))

        self.colorpicker_btn = Button(text='Couleurs', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos=(5, 60))
        self.colorpicker_btn.bind(on_press=self.roue_de_couleurs)

        # Create color boxes
        self.saved_colors = [Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos=(355 + 50 * i, 5)) for i in range(31)]
        for btn in self.saved_colors:
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.peintre.definir_couleur(btn.background_color))
        btn_exporter = Button(text='Exporter', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50), pos=(40, 385))
        btn_exporter.bind(on_release=lambda instance: self.export_to_png('dessin.png'))

        parent.add_widget(self.peintre)
        parent.add_widget(btn_effacer)
        parent.add_widget(btn_ligne_fine)
        parent.add_widget(btn_ligne_epaisse)
        parent.add_widget(btn_ligne_plus_epaisse)
        parent.add_widget(btn_ligne_encore_plus_epaisse)
        parent.add_widget(btn_quitter)
        parent.add_widget(btn_rouge)
        parent.add_widget(btn_vert)
        parent.add_widget(btn_bleu)
        parent.add_widget(btn_jaune)
        parent.add_widget(btn_turquoise)
        parent.add_widget(btn_rose)
        parent.add_widget(self.colorpicker_btn)
        parent.add_widget(btn_blanc)
        parent.add_widget(btn_ouvrir)
        for btn in self.saved_colors:
            parent.add_widget(btn)
        parent.add_widget(slider)
        parent.add_widget(btn_exporter)

        self.file_chooser = FileChooserListView()
        self.file_chooser.bind(on_submit=self.ouvrir_fichier_selectionné)
        self.file_popup = Popup(title='Choisir un fichier', content=self.file_chooser, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        return parent

    def adjust_brush_size(self, instance, value):
        # Met à jour la taille de la ligne et du point basée sur la valeur du slider
        self.peintre.definir_largeur_ligne(value)
        self.peintre.definir_largeur_point(value * 2)  # Par exemple, le point est toujours le double de la largeur de la ligne

    def roue_de_couleurs(self, instance):
        self.color_picker = ColorPicker()
        self.color_picker.bind(color=self.def_couleur)
        popup = Popup(title='Sélectionnez une couleur', content=self.color_picker, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()
        popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.save_color_to_box)

    def def_couleur(self, instance, color):
        self.peintre.definir_couleur(color)

    def ajuster_couleur(self, couleur):
        facteur = 0.2
        moyenne = sum(couleur[:3]) / 3
        nouvelle_couleur = [(c + facteur * (c - moyenne)) for c in couleur[:3]]
        nouvelle_couleur = [min(max(0, c), 1) for c in nouvelle_couleur]
        return tuple(nouvelle_couleur + [couleur[3]])

    def save_color_to_box(self, instance):
        couleur = self.color_picker.color
        satcoul = self.ajuster_couleur(couleur)
        couleur_assignée = False
        for btn in self.saved_colors:
            if btn.background_color == [1, 1, 1, 1] and not couleur_assignée:
                btn.background_color = satcoul
                couleur_assignée = True

    def configurer_peintre(self, largeur_ligne, largeur_point):
        self.peintre.definir_largeur_ligne(largeur_ligne)
        self.peintre.definir_largeur_point(largeur_point)

    def effacer_toile(self, obj):
        self.peintre.effacer_toile()
        print('Effacé !')

    def ouvrir_fichier(self):
        # Afficher le FileChooser
        self.file_popup.open()

    def ouvrir_fichier_selectionné(self, instance, selection, _):
    # Fermer le FileChooser
      self.file_popup.dismiss()

    # Vérifier si un fichier a été sélectionné
      if selection:
        chemin_fichier = selection[0]
        self.peintre.effacer_toile()  # Effacer le dessin actuel

        # Charger l'image et la convertir en une instruction graphique
        image = Image(source=chemin_fichier, allow_stretch=True)
        image.size = self.peintre.size  # Redimensionner à la taille du canvas
        image.pos = (0, 0)  # Positionner en haut à gauche du canvas

        with self.peintre.canvas:
            # Créer un rectangle avec l'image comme texture
            texture = image.texture
            rectangle = Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=image.pos, size=image.size)

        print(f'Fichier ouvert: {chemin_fichier}')

    def export_to_png(self, filename):
            print(f"Exporting to {filename}...")
            
            try:
                print('Size', self.peintre.size, 'Filename: ', filename)
                self.peintre.size = (Window.size[0], Window.size[1])
                self.peintre.export_to_png(filename)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error while exporting: {e}")
                raise e

    def enregistrer(self):
        if self.peintre.dessin:
            content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            msg = Label(text='Vous avez des changements non enregistrés. Voulez-vous enregistrer ?')
            btn_layout = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height='70', orientation='horizontal')
            oui_btn = Button(text='Oui', on_release=lambda *args: self.sauvegarder_toile())
            non_btn = Button(text='Non', on_release=lambda *args: App().stop())
            btn_layout.add_widget(oui_btn)
            btn_layout.add_widget(non_btn)
            content.add_widget(msg)
            content.add_widget(btn_layout)
            self.save_popup = Popup(title='Confirmation de Sauvegarde', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 200), auto_dismiss=False)
            self.save_popup.open()
        else:
            print('Rien à enregistrer')
            self.stop()

    def sauvegarder_toile(self):
        if self.peintre.dessin:
            # Créer une boîte de dialogue d'entrée textuelle pour saisir le nouveau nom du fichier
            content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            msg = Label(text='Saisissez le nouveau nom du fichier (sans extension) :')
            input_filename = TextInput(hint_text='Nom du fichier')
            btn_layout = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height='70', orientation='horizontal')
            sauvegarder_btn = Button(text='Sauvegarder', on_release=lambda *args: self.sauvegarder_avec_nom(input_filename.text))
            annuler_btn = Button(text='Annuler', on_release=lambda *args: self.save_popup.dismiss())
            btn_layout.add_widget(sauvegarder_btn)
            btn_layout.add_widget(annuler_btn)
            content.add_widget(msg)
            content.add_widget(input_filename)
            content.add_widget(btn_layout)
            self.save_popup = Popup(title='Sauvegarder le dessin', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(500, 250), auto_dismiss=False)
            self.save_popup.open()
        else:
            print('Rien à enregistrer')

    def sauvegarder_avec_nom(self, filename):
        if filename:
            if not filename.endswith('.png'):
                filename += '.png'  # Ajouter l'extension .png si elle n'est pas déjà présente
            self.export_to_png(filename)
            print(f'Dessin sauvegardé sous {filename} !')
        else:
            print('Nom de fichier invalide.')
        self.save_popup.dismiss()
        AppPaint().stop()

    def profil(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AppPaint().run()

The code is mostly in french but I think that the problem is in the ouvrir_fichier_selectionné method, sorry about the language, it's for my coding major so I have to put it in french
I tried using Blackbox AI and CHATGPT to help me but they couldn't help so here I am asking people that knows more than me :)

In your build() method you are using a basic Widget as the root of your GUI:
parent = Widget()

The Widget class is not designed to be a container for other Widgets, and does not handle things like size_hint (and many others). So, when you add  the WidgetPaint object (which has the default size_hint of (1, 1)), its size never gets adjusted from that default size of (100, 100). Then, when you create an Image from a saved png file, its size is set by the code:
image.size = self.peintre.size  # Redimensionner à la taille du canvas

But the size of self.peintre is the default (100, 100) as described above. So that Image with size of (100, 100) and pos of (0, 0) will appear in the lower left of your GUI.
The fix is to change the root of your GUI to a Layout, such as FloatLayout, which correctly handles size_hint and will set the size of the WidgetPaint object:
parent = FloatLayout()

